# Where can I download pdo_sqlite.so or sqlite.so

Tags: apache, zend-framework, sqlite, pdo

I'm running an zend application on mamp (MacOS), and I need the apache extension pdo for sqlite (pdo_sqlite.so or sqlite.os).

Do you know where I can downlaod it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its already included into your mamp installations , you must see this [link](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/faq/which-php-modules-are-included) to see the included modules

Answer (score 0):

Your php.ini must include a line "extension=sqlite3.so"